# How to count no.of series added in line chart using jfreechart?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have designed the line chart with 4 series using ireport. I need to count those series in my custom class using jfreechart

```
LineAndShapeRenderer lineAndShapeRenderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
lineAndShapeRenderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0,new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER,TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT));
lineAndShapeRenderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(1,new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE5,TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT));
lineAndShapeRenderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(2,new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12,TextAnchor.BOTTOM_RIGHT));
lineAndShapeRenderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(3,new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE1,TextAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT));
```

insteadof hardcoded above I need to use like **lineAndShapeRenderer.getSeriesCount();**

but I didn't get such methods or other clues to set as below

```
for (int i=0 ;i<lineAndShapeRenderer.getSeriesCount();i++)
    lineAndShapeRenderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(i,new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE1,TextAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT));
```

Kindly help me out on this to get no of series used in line chart - ireport.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of series from the dataset used to create your chart. For example, a [`CategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/CategoryDataset.html) has a row for each series. You can do something like this:

```
int seriesCount = dataset.getRowCount();
```

Edit: In a comment, you say

> `categoryPlot.getLegendItems().getItemCount()`…helped me to getting no. series used in line chart.

The legend items are part of the view; I'd ask the model. If you have a reference to the plot, you can get a reference to the dataset:

```
CategoryPlot categoryPlot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
CategoryDataset dataset = categoryPlot. getDataset();
int seriesCount = dataset.getRowCount();
```

Comment: CategoryPlot categoryPlot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
int SeriesCount = categoryPlot.getLegendItems().getItemCount();
above statement, helped me to getting no. series used in line chart.

Comment: @Viswa: That's an interesting way, but the dataset is more reliable. Edited.

Comment: Will try let you know.. :) Thanks for your comment buddy.. :)